# How to conditionally group into column without using FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: postgresql

I want to turn

```
TABLEA:
id      type               amount
A       'Customer'          100
A       'Parter'            10
A       'Customer'          200
A       'Parter'            20
B       'Parter'            555
```

I can hardcode the type, don't need to be dynamic, these types are enum

```
RESULT:
id      customer_array  customer_sum   partner_array  partner_sum 
A       [100, 200]      300            [10, 20]       30           
B       []              0              [555]          555
```

Right now 
   I am using two aggregate function

```
   WITH customer AS (
      SELECT
        table_A,
        json_agg(row_to_json(amount)) AS customer_array,
        sum(amount)                   AS customer_sum
      FROM table_A WHERE type='Customer' 
      GROUP BY id
   ), partner AS (
      SELECT
        table_A,
        json_agg(row_to_json(amount)) AS partner_array,
        sum(amount)                   AS partner_sum
      FROM table_A WHERE type='Partner' 
      GROUP BY id
   ) SELECT 
       id,
       COALESCE(customer_array, '[]')    AS customer_array,
       COALESCE(customer_sum, 0)         AS customer_sum,
       COALESCE(partner_array, '[]')     AS partner_array,
       COALESCE(partner_sum, 0)          AS partner_sum
   FROM customer FULL OUTER JOIN partner USING (id)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve what I want without querying twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple conditional aggregation as far as I can tell:

```
select id, 
       array_agg(amount) filter (where type = 'Customer') as customer_array,
       sum(amount) filter (where type = 'Customer') as customer_sum,
       array_agg(amount) filter (where type = 'Partner') as partner_array,
       sum(amount) filter (where type = 'Partner') as partner_sum
from table_a
group by id;
```

If you want an empty array instead of a `NULL` value, wrap the aggregation functions into a `coalesce()`:

```
select id, 
       coalesce((array_agg(amount) filter (where type = 'Customer')),'{}') as customer_array,
       coalesce((sum(amount) filter (where type = 'Customer')),0) as customer_sum,
       coalesce((array_agg(amount) filter (where type = 'Partner')),'{}') as partner_array,
       coalesce((sum(amount) filter (where type = 'Partner')),0) as partner_sum
from table_a
group by id;
```

Comment: thank you this is clean:) do you know if this way or using CASE is better for performance?

Comment: `case` vs. `filter` doesn't make a difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the case statement.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-conditional.html

I don't have a postgres server to try this. But overall the syntax should be as below.

```
    SELECT
        table_A,
        case 
            when Type='Customer' 
         then json_agg(row_to_json(amount)) 
         else [] 
         end AS customer_array,
        case 
            when Type='Customer' 
             sum(amount)  
             else 0 
        end
        AS customer_sum,

        case 
            when Type='Partner' 
         then json_agg(row_to_json(amount)) 
         else [] 
         end AS partner_array
        case 
            when Type='Partner' 
             sum(amount)  
             else 0 
        end
         From table_A
    GROUP BY id
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `postgresql` not SQL Server